# Как сохранить сессию при парсинге?

Tags: python, selenium, парсер

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос, мне нужно запарсить закрытую часть сайта, что я делаю, я логинюсь в пайтоне потом получаю нужную страницу, и начинаю парсить, но так как я только начал, много доработок приходится вносить, и каждый раз авторизироваться тратиться много времени, поэтому возникает вопрос, как сохранить эту сессию, чтобы в другом модуле продолжить парсить, может посоветуете тему которую надо в гугле грызть, я просто сообразить не могу пока, либо же готовый пример видели на сайте, можете ссылку скинуть, заранее большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Что типа такого надо:

```
import pickle


FILENAME = ''


if новая_сесия:
    pickle.dump(DRIVER.get_cookies() , open(FILENAME, 'wb'))
else:
    for cookie in pickle.load(open(FILENAME, 'rb')):
        DRIVER.add_cookie(cookie)
```